# mount a drive in fstab using UUID not working

Tags: boot, mount, fstab

I tried to mount a drive, but it fails on reboot, and I have to press S to skip so I can log in. Is there a certain way I should add it to the fstab? Here is what I see when I type blkid

```
/dev/sdb1: UUID="cf71fa06-d1db-47e1-893d-c0069aa1f77f" SEC_TYPE="ext2" TYPE="ext3"
```

I can mount it using the old way and it works fine

```
/dev/sdb1    /media/PLEXdrive   ext3    defaults     0        2
```

It used to work, but I formatted the drive that was 12.04 and installed 14.04.5 server. Not sure what im missing here. The drive I am mounting is a data drive with all my PLEX media server videos and movies, etc

Comment: UUID="cf71fa06-d1db-47e1-893d-c0069aa1f77f" /media/PLEXdrive   ext4    defaults     0        2         should work. Change ext4 to ext3 if you're running an older version of Ubuntu.

Comment: that worked. Did it work because I left the quotes around the UUID? I dont recall letting the quotes the last time I mounted a drive.

Comment: eh... actually, you could leave off the quotes around the UUID. Did you have to change the ext4 to ext3 for Ubuntu 14.04? I forget when they default started using ext4. I'll post as an answer  and maybe you can rate/accept it.

Comment: I did have to change to ext3. The drive was first installed on ubuntu 12.04 LTS, and I just keep it the way it is and use it now on 14.04.5 LTS. Im not a linux guru, so I dont know if ext4 would work. I could try it and see. I assume that you have to use what is shown when sudo blkid is run. Thanks for your help

Comment: You can convert ext3 to ext4 if you want to take advantage of its features.

Comment: Thanks david. Do you feel there is any benefit to doing that? Its just a data drive, but as I said, im no expert, and I am all for any real benefits of doing somthing. If you feel there is a benefit, can you link me some instructions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As above, this should work:

```
UUID=cf71fa06-d1db-47e1-893d-c0069aa1f77f /media/PLEXdrive ext3 defaults 0 2
```

Change `ext3` to `ext4` if you're running a newer version of Ubuntu.

Comment: Glad you got it going! Cheers, Al